# How to extract from a .GFS file

Tags: archiving, extract

My colleacue has left me some files for a project I am working on before he left the company, but some of the files have been merges into a .gfs file. Does anybody know of an application either for Windows XP or Linux (Debian/Ubuntu) that would allow me to retrieve the files?

Answer (score 0):

The .GFS files might have been produced by [Microsoft Office Groove](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SharePoint_Workspace), a predecessor of Microsoft SharePoint.

Try to use a [Trial](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26946) version do get the contents. The product is no longer marketed by Microsoft.